# How to express and remove * multiplier within matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have imported matrix/array data into matlab. The data shows all duplicates as multiples. Example.

```
4591,  3*6036,  7763
```

Whereas, I need to fully express the duplicates within the array. Corrected data:

```
4591,   6036,   6036,    6036,    7763
```

What is the best way to insert the full expression of the multiples/duplicates within the existing array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
data= '4591,  3*6036,  7763 ';
newdata= regexprep(data,'(\d+)\*(\d+)','${strjoin(repmat({$2},1,str2num($1)),'',  '')}')
```

Comment: This is a great answer!